# An unexpected error occurred: cp "$BUILD_PATH"/framework/cordova-$VERSION.jar

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to deploy phonegap for android and iOS. iOS works fine but while creating the android project like this in terminal:

```
./create ~/Documents/testapp_android org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld
```

I am getting these errors:

```
cp: /Users/Pim/Documents/cordova-2.3.0/cordova-android/framework/cordova-2.3.0.jar: No such file or directory
An unexpected error occurred: cp "$BUILD_PATH"/framework/cordova-$VERSION.jar "$PROJECT_PATH"/libs/cordova-$VERSION.jar exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I got the ADT etcetera properly installed. Does anyone have any other points that may help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by just copying the cordova-2.3.0.jar out of the phonegap-android folder to the cordova folder. Doesn't happen automatically appearantly.

It's not described in the manual of phonegap nor cordova.

Hope it helps anyone..

Comment: Hi can you clarify how you solved this problem? I am having the same problem. I do not see a .jar file in my 'cordova-android' folder. Thanks

Comment: @user1530249: I don't see it either, have you figured it out?